# Frame Buffer Image Viewer Load Subsequent Image

Tags: python, image, slideshow, fullscreen

I was having some trouble using fbi in the following manner:

```
import os
import time

while True:
    os.system('sudo fbi -m "1920x1080-60" --autoup -t 10 -noverbose -d /dev/fb0 -T 2 /home/pi/Ads/8.jpg')
    time.sleep(5)
    os.system('sudo fbi -m "1920x1080-60" --autoup -u -t 10 -noverbose -readahead -d /dev/fb0 -T 2 /home/pi/Ads/squirrel_0.jpg')
    time.sleep(5)
```

What I want to do is display images using a script, or from starting a slideshow at start-up, and be able to determine which image is being displayed at a particular time.  This will allow my main script to know which image is being displayed and apply it to the data I am accruing with my camera.

What is troublesome about the above script is that the two images would flicker simultaneously the longer they were switched.

I would like to know is is there a log file fbi uses to determine which image is being displayed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what do you want, what do you expect to happen and where things go wrong?

Comment: I want to be able to let my main script know which image is being displayed with the fbi slideshow somehow, if it could be done.  I created the above script to test if I could individually display images from python, which would allow me to control which picture is displayed, rather than determining that from the slideshow.